# Apoyo, como cambiar formato de tipo 'char', a Date, Las datos están asi : 1/16/2022, también asi, 1/5/2022, cambiar formato a Date

Tags: r, date, formato

He importado un archivo .csv en RStudio, una columna que contiene datos de fecha, está en formato tipo CHAR, los datos vienen asi: 1/16/2022 , 1/6/2022, 10/1/2022, 10/20/2022, como se puede cambiar a formato DATE usando R

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué has intentado o investigado? Convertir una cadena con formato, en fecha, es una de las tareas más comunes en cualquier lenguaje. Leer [la documentación](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/date/versions/1.2-40/topics/as.date) es lo primero que deberías hacer. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada por no mostrar un [mre] de lo que has intentado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas facil:

```
require( lubridate )
ejemplos <- c( '1/16/2022' , '1/6/2022', '10/1/2022', '10/20/2022' )

fechas <- mdy( ejemplos )   # <-----------------------

fechas
#[1] "2022-01-16" "2022-01-06" "2022-10-01" "2022-10-20"

class( fechas )
#[1] "Date"
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).